# change location of google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, maps

i want to integrate google maps on my webpage

the way i am using to do that is this :

```
<section id="contact" class="map">
        <iframe width="100%" height="500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
 <br />
        <small>
           <!-- <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>-->
        </small>
        </iframe>
    </section>
```

Here is a live plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/Pakox2L63kO0i5dR9iPh?p=preview

**Question:** How do i change the location to something else. I mean from where on google maps can i pick the location and paste it as it is in the src section to have a new location.

( for example i want to point to this location : https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Cafe+Coffee+Day/@18.558569,73.791647,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x3bc2bed9d33bfd3b:0x913791c91ba6cb4c )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use that code if you want to manipulate your map.

here is the basic sample code of google map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Simple Map</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
 }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

you can learn more this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    alert(e.latLng());
    });
```

when you click the map..it will get its lat and lng

Comment: i was able to implement that code too. (for the above snippet)
it would be helpful if you could give me a way to **get the LatLng of a location on google maps**

Comment: its working 
it would be alert(e.latLng);
http://plnkr.co/edit/pJHuU9DacD1JwO8G0jhP?p=preview

but the issue would be that i **want** to search the location on google maps and from there get the lat and lng of the location.

but in the code snippet above i would have to manually drag to the location and then click and after that i would be able to get the lat and lng( which is very painful)

is there a direct way where i can search and get the lat lng of the location

Comment: also when i manually went to the location and copied the lat and lng and pasted it in the javascript

 its not highlighting the latlng that i gave in the javascript when i run the plunkr again 
http://plnkr.co/edit/pJHuU9DacD1JwO8G0jhP?p=preview

Comment: i just want to have the locations highlighted when the user visits my page. like this http://plnkr.co/edit/Pakox2L63kO0i5dR9iPh?p=preview

Comment: you can find more example in google map tutorial..you want to show the lat lng after search right? its simple as 1+1..
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/ find the search in this example

Answer (score 0):

you are using an iframe wich is hard to manipulate you can use the google maps api .
its costumable and you can change a lot of settings :
[**Google Maps API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: i dont want to have any dynamic behavior with the google maps thing.
it would be a one time thing for my use case, so if there could be direct way